# I don't understand why an ID is not more specific than a class

Tags: css, class, css-specificity

I've got:

```
<div class="cardDisplay">
<img class="cardImg"  id="cardImg4" alt="Card" src="picture.jpg" width="148" height="236.8" title="">
        </div>
```

Here's my CSS.

```
.cardDisplay
    {
    width: 1020px;
    background-color: #040D14;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    }

.cardImg
    {
    padding:0px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    /* background-color: black; */
    }   

#cardImg4
    {
    border: 20px solid white;
    padding-right: 30px: 
    }
```

The problem is I cannot get the, I thought, more specific ID to override the class.  I've tried doing it a number of different ways with no luck.  I'm using Chrome if that matters.  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970730/css-id-vs-class

Comment: It's not a dupe, the rule is simply ignored due to the colon, see answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a colon `:` instead of a semi-colon `;` in your padding-right style for `#cardImg4`.  The rule probably isn't being applied at all.

Comment: Well.... that's embarrassing.  Should I delete this post?  At least my faith has returned in my understanding of specificity.

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that you have a `:` not `;` after the `#cardimg4 padding-right`. This might affect it.