# CSS not being applied to div tag

Tags: css, html

Having a small issue with a div tag as it's not picking up the CSS I have for it.

I notice then when I inspect the element in Firefox and Chrome.  I see one html element that has a div tag and it applies the CSS properly.  I then look at another, and while the html code is almost identical, it's not applying the CSS.

Here is one html code with div tag that works:

```
<tr>
        <td class="style1">
            <label><div ID="Login">Login:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="login" id="loginpassword" type="text" name="username"     
maxlength="75">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Here's the CSS for the loginpassword ID:

```
#loginpassword {width:150px;}
```

Here is my 2nd html snippet of code (the one that isn't applying the CSS):

```
<tr>
        <td class="style1">
            <label><div ID="Password">Password:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="login" id="loginpassword2" type="password" name="password" 
maxlength="75">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

And here's the CSS for the loginpassword2 ID:

```
#loginpassword2 {width:150px;}
```

So they almost 100% identical, but the ID of loginpassword2 isn't applying the CSS, whereas loginpassword is applying the CSS.  Strange.  I can't understand why one works and the other doesn't.

Any clue on this?  If you need more information, please do let me know.

Thank you advance for your reply.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're trying to apply any CSS to a div tag

Comment: Your html is not well formed.

Comment: I'm applying CSS to the ID inside the <input> field for a form box to set the width.  Maybe this isn't the best method for applying width on a box (for username/password).

Comment: That html above...yes, I know it's a mess.  I have to circle back and clean it up when I have time.  Right now, I'm just trying to get these two boxes the same width that shows across all browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters:

```
<td class="style1">
    <label><div ID="Login">Login:</label>
</td>
<td>
    <input class="login" id="loginpassword" type="text" name="username" maxlength="75">
    </div>
```

That is terribly formed HTML. You can't open a `<div>` tag inside a `<td>` and close it inside another `<td>`.

Consider validating your HTML: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options

---

Not only that, but you are also using the class `login` for the both of them, so why not take advantage of that, since you're styling them the same?

```
.login {width:150px;}
```

That will affect all elements with the `login` class.

---

**Further Reading:**

*CSS IDs & Classes*

- Check out Jonathon Sampson's example in his answer to [CSS ID vs Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970730/css-id-vs-class).
- http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

*Valid HTML*

- http://www.leemunroe.com/how-important-is-valid-html-web-standards/

Comment: The closing </div> stems from the open <div>:  '<label><div ID="Password">Password:</label>'   Now that I look at it, I do have the </div> in the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you!.. Using what you suggested worked perfect.  Now I'll go clean up all this extra junk I have in the code...

Comment: Validate html - yes, I must.  Thanks for the link from Jonathon Sampson.  I'll study up on that.  As for the login class - I only have one in the entire site so I'm good w/using your suggestion.  Really appreciate your help and everyone's help here.

Answer (score 0):

Apply css for class level instead of id.

Comment: I was always under the impression you couldn't apply CSS to class - but aww, I learn you can.  Good to know.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your html layout like

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="style1">
<label id="lbllogin" runat="server">Login:</label>
</td>
<td>
<input class="login" id="loginpassword" type="text" name="username"     
maxlength="75" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="style1">
<label id="lblpwd" runat="server">Password:</label>
</td>
<td>
<input class="login" id="loginpassword2" type="password" name="password" 
maxlength="75" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

> #loginpassword {width:150px;}
>
> #loginpassword2 {width:150px;}

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score -1):

Do one thing. Just remove the class="login" from both input tags