# Define style of Div tag

Tags: html, css

I want to define the style of Div based on a CSS file. The CSS code I have written is:

```
.body
{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 1px;
    color: black;
    background-color:lightgrey;
}
```

I want the background of each Div section to be light-grey. What's wrong with the above code?

Edited:

This is my HTML code. I changed the Div class as suggested below, but it is not working. Please also check whether the Link tag contains path correctly or not. The CSS file is located in a Lib folder, up-one-level.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Add/Update Political Party</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=".\Lib\entryformstyle.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sectionEntryForm" class="div">
            <table id="tblEntryForm" cols="2">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">Add/Update Political Party</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Party full name:</td>
                    <td><input id="inPartyFullName" name="inPartyFullName" accept="text/plain" maxlength="80" class="inputBoxStyle"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Party short name (initials):</td>
                    <td><input id="inPartyShortName" name="inPartyShortName" accept="text/plain" maxlength="80" class="inputBoxStyle"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The link tag is wrong. See my answer.

Comment: tip: for the links inside html use / not \ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*ALL* DIVs:

```
div
{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 1px;
    color: black;
    background-color:lightgrey;
}
```

DIVs with class "body":

```
div.body
{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 1px;
    color: black;
    background-color:lightgrey;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Nothing, you just have to use `<div class="body">` to make the DIV pick it up.

Answer (score 2):

If your CSS file is *up one level*, you have to include it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/entryformstyle.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: @Franz: It worked, but it is aligning in center in IE, but not in FireFox?

Comment: Try to use `.div, .div * {` as the selector.

Answer (score 1):

try deleting the period (.) before 'body'

edit: it is also probably worth having a quick read of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602168/in-css-what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-declaring-a-set-of-styles)

it explains the difference between "." and '#' when defining styles.

Comment: In this case, it would be better to replace `.body` with `div`.

Comment: @JT: The CSS worked when I deleted the period, but it is not recognizing the class name. Also, can I define my own class name?

Comment: yep! you can, however you will need to add reference it with the period (.) and the new class name; ie .myClass{background-color:lightgrey;}

Comment: -> this is assuming you have defined the class with: <div class="myClass"></div>

Answer (score 1):

This only works on the class "body", that is

```
 <div class="body">
```

If you want it to work on any divs, the selector ("`.body`" in your sample code) should be `div`.

Answer (score 0):

For this style to work, your div needs to be written like this:

```
<div class="body">Your text here</div>
```

In other words, the **.** in front of the body in your css tells the browser to apply the style in the braces to an element whose **class** is named **body**.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
background-color:lightgrey;
```

to

```
background-color:silver;
```

or

```
background-color:#CCC;
```

This is assuming that your div has the body class applied:

```
<div class="body"></div>
```

Comment: Ah thanks - I did a quick check but obviously not thorough enough!

Answer (score 0):

Either use

```
div
{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 1px;
    color: black;
    background-color:lightgrey;/*#CCC*/
}
```

to set background color of all div

Or use

```
div.body
{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 1px;
    color: black;
    background-color:lightgrey;
}
```

and set `<div class="body"></div>` for each div.

You can use inline stylesheet as :

```
<div style="background-color:lightgrey;"></div>
```