# How to click an element when using Capybara for test

Tags: ruby, capybara

I tried this:

```
page.find("#parentNode").first(".childClass").click
```

but got the error: `NoMethodError:undefined method 'click' for nil:NilClass`

How can I click `childNode1` or `childNode2`

```
<div id="parentNode">
     <div id="childNode1" class="childClass">
         <img src="path img1"></img>
     </div>
     <div id="childNode2" class="childClass">
        <img src="path img2"></img>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: Doesn't `page.find('#childNode1').click` work? I'm not surprised you're getting an error as none of the IDs or classes you're trying to match appear in the HTML you show.

Comment: NoMethodError:undefined method `click' for nil:NilClass

Comment: This question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602168/in-css-what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-declaring-a-set-of-styles

Comment: i update my code pls check again

Comment: Since your username is 'beginerdeveloper', I should point out an important debugging strategy: work incrementally. You have a long chain of methods, and the exception is saying you can't call the `click` method on `nil:NilClass`. That means that `page.find("#parentNode").first(".childClass")` is returning `nil`. That is, in itself, a chain of methods, so just start by calling `page.find("#parentNode")` and check the result, and build up your function from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use click method: find("#childNode1").click

[Click](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element#click-instance_method)

Comment: have you added the param "js: true" to the it block ?